# Maria DB: how to execute a sum between times in SEC_TO_TIME argument?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm actually in this situation (these are part of a unique query):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(_staffTime) AS _staffTimeTotal
```

I have another value expressed in seconds (from another table): _staffTimeBo

Both _staffTimeBo and _staffTime are so calculated:

```
SELECT SUM(tiStaffTimeBo) AS _staffTimeBo FROM table1

SELECT SUM(tiStaffTime) AS _staffTime FROM table2
```

What I need is get the sum in y/m/d hh:mmm:ss resulting by _staffTimeBo + _staffTime

I tried several solutions but no one gave me the right result

Example I tried this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(_staffTimeBo) + SUM(_staffTime)) AS _staffTimeTotal
```

AND

```
SELECT tiStaffTimeBo AS _staffTimeBo FROM table1

SELECT tiStaffTime AS _staffTime FROM table2
```

I'm now simply trying this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(_staffTimeBo + _staffTime ) AS _staffTimeTotal
```

AND

```
SELECT SUM(tiStaffTimeBo) AS _staffTimeBo FROM table1

SELECT SUM(tiStaffTime) AS _staffTime FROM table2
```

Anyway, also this "solution" doesn't work

Is there a way to sum this two times?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected output?.

Comment: Hi: if I set tiStaffTimeBo= 60 seconds and tiStaffTime=60 seconds I expect that SEC_TO_TIME(60 + 60)= 00:02:00 Instead I receive, by a check (but keep in mind that I work on 733 records and I can't check all) 0 for records where tiStaffTime >0 and 00:01:00 for records where tiStaffTime=0 and tiStaffTimeBo>0. I hope to be clear, thanks

Comment: I can't quite understand the problem. Perhaps the following [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UQ8n4eS_) can help.